# Navigation issue where the links move when another page loads

Tags: css, uinavigationbar

I'm having an issue with my navigation. If your on any page, and click another- when that next page loads, my nave bar seems to move back and forth.

Its hard to explain, but if you start on http://jeffreydowellphotography.com
and then click the "contact" page, my navigation links seem to move closer, and then back to the correct position.

```
/* ---------->>> navigation alignment/spacing on right <<<-----------*/

    .header-alignment-left.header-navigation-split #topNav { position: absolute; right: 18px; }
```

/* ---------->>> navigation hover padding <<<-----------*/

```
    .logo-image #topNav nav li a { padding: 5px 15px; line-height:100%;}
    #nav a{ border-top:0px solid transparent; }
    #nav .subnav{margin-top:0}
```

/* ---------->>> navigation divider lines <<<-----------*/

```
    #nav a{ border-right:1.5px solid #3b5998; height: 20px;}
    #nav li:last-child a{ border-right:0; }
```

/* ---------->>> dropdown menu inside spacing <<<-----------*/

```
    #header #topNav nav .folder ul li {padding:0 24px 12px; position: relative;  }
    #header { margin-top: 10px !important; }
    #topNav { margin-top: 53px; }
    #nav .subnav ul { padding-bottom:15px !important;}
    #nav .subnav ul { padding-top:15px !important;}
```

f

Comment: I'm not sure why it's doing it, but I can only recreate it in Chrome. IE and FF look fine.

Comment: its doing it in Safari too.

Comment: it might be a javascript thing, because if I click on something under Information, only Portfolio and Information move. So everything to the left of the clicked one. Since its not all of them all the type, I don't think its the CSS

Comment: this is a template based site from squarespace, so i dont think its java. Im only able to add in custom css, and i think i messed it up somewhere.

Comment: weird... I went to look at it again and its not doing it anymore... Anyway try taking out your css and adding it back in just a bit at a time to see if you can find the problem

Comment: thats crazy, i just went back to it, and same as you, its not doing it anymore. I havent even changed a thing. weird indeed.

Comment: squarespace bug? i dunno. well here's to hoping it doesn't come back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning of loading the page is slightly wider than when the page is completely loaded because the scrollbar appears not immediately. Your site is 100% wide and because that difference of width, the navigation bar slightly moves.